Is there a way to emulate relative referencing in Excel?
So I'm trying to make a template to help streamline some QA work going forward and I'm trying to make it so that we can just make copies of one folder with the functional specs and the QA plan and use that as a sort of automated process. I'm running into the issue that Excel links need to be absolute so it'll break the moment the first copy of the folder is made.
Theoretically I think that if I put into a cell a spot where a person can put the one drive link to a document, then using names and other references to that, I might be able to emulate a relative reference, but has anyone ever actually tried something like this before? Am I better off writing code for this in some other language rather than forcing a proverbial square peg into a round hole?

There's a VBA solution for fixing up various types of link by macropod that's quite widely referenced, here:https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html . I think if that isn't going to do enough for you, you should really try to describe in more depth what it doesn't do (you might not be able to use VBA because it's client-side only, for example) and what you've tried. IIN my view, LINK fields are a bit of a liability and best avoided if possible.

It's certainly worth ensuring that they function correctly in whatever folder environment you need to use (e.g., IME links saved in a word document to an Excel moniker in a .xlsx in a local copy of a One Drive actually contain the https:// address of the Excel target on the One server, which you might hope would make the link usable wherever the Word document was opened. But it doesn't. IN fact, even trying to point at the local path name of the .xslx instead doesn't work - looks like something in OLE doesn't like the path. But perhaps others have a different experience.

I'm trying to make a template for people at work where a functional specs document. I'm not familiar with VBA at all. If it isn't possible to do without some ridiculous workaround then that's fine. I'll just make the excel document itself as automated as I can.

@jonsson Sorry about that. I didn't mean for it to sound like that. But thanks anyway for your help, though. This has made me curious about VBA. Never used it before. I just hope my supervisor doesn't mind.

thank you so much for the help. Since I feel that it's right to keep you updated: I ultimately went with just keeping some of the stuff local within the excel spreadsheet itself. And while it is clunky (because I'm making it in excel, I'm hardly surprised), my supervisor loved what I was able to do in the end.

Will do! Stack Overflow has been my go-to for years to answer my questions about writing code aside from tutorial sites (w3schools as an example) or the documentation itself. Figured it was high time I made an account at this point and start asking more direct questions myself if I couldn't find an answer. Thank you so much for being my guide through my first question! I'll be sure to save some screenshots if/when this question gets deleted so I can reference it as needed.
